# Error when use javascript set timeout set last image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="animate-image">
    <img class="first" src="first_image.png" data-hover="second_image.png" data-static="last_image.png">
</div>
```

And my script

```
jQuery('.animate-image').on("hover", function (e) {
     let first_img_src = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src");
     let second_img_src = jQuery(this).find("img").data("hover");
     let last_img_src = jQuery(this).find("img").data("static");
     if(jQuery(this).find("img").hasClass("first")) {
          jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", second_img_src).removeClass("first").addClass("second");
     }
     var timer = setTimeout(function(){
          if(jQuery(this).find("img").hasClass("second")) {
               jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", last_img_src).removeClass("second").addClass("static");    
          }
    }, 3000);
});
```

When hover first image, it will load second image, but error after 3 seconds it now run last image

Comment: what is the `error`?

Comment: Error can't load last image after 3 seconds

Comment: `this` context issue. Use an arrow function in your `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
    if(jQuery(this).find("img").hasClass("second")) {
         jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", last_img_src).removeClass("second").addClass("static");    
    }
}, 3000);
```

In the above, the normal normal callback function i:e `setTimeout(function() {})` is creating it's own `this` and no longer refer to the `hovered element`. Instead use arrow function i:e `setTimeout(() => {})`, which won't create it's own `this` and will refer to immediate enclosing function `this`, in this case it is `hovered element`.

```
var timer = setTimeout(() => { 
    if(jQuery(this).find("img").hasClass("second")) {
         jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", last_img_src).removeClass("second").addClass("static");    
    }
}, 3000);
```